# file_get_contents: failed to open stream

Tags: controllers

I'm trying to read a txt file with a controller that i've set up.  However, I'm unsure where to place this file and how to call it correctly.  Everything i've tried has resulted in the following error:

> 2015-01-21T13:57:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   file_get_contents(youtube_videos_only_hash.txt): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /opt/magento/app/code/local/namespace/module/controllers/IndexController.php
>   on line 9

Any help would be appreciated.

The error in question is related to the filepath:

```
    $filepath = 'images/youtube_videos_only_hash.txt';
    $hashes2 = file_get_contents($filepath);
```

Comment: It seems to be purely PHP-related. You should try `file_exists($filepath)` before attempting to read it. Tell us what's the output.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about pure PHP.

Comment: @mbalparda I dont think so.  It's about pure php within a magento context.

Comment: Opinions does not matter here. If i mark this question as off topic and mods/other users decide it is off topic it will be closed.

Comment: @mbalparda this isn't an opinion.  This is also a magento file directory and path question.

Comment: @JulienLachal I tried to log the result of file_exists($filepath) and i'm not getting anything within the log.

Comment: then just `var_dump(file_exists($filepath));die;` that should suffice as far as seeing results is concerned.

Comment: have you tried `file_get_contents('./'.$filepath)` ?

Comment: @JulienLachal yes, Reindex 'Em All gave me an acceptable solution.  Thanks though.

Comment: np, glad you had it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save file in `var/youtube_videos_only_hash.txt` and try this:

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'youtube_videos_only_hash.txt';
$hashes2 = file_get_contents($path);
```